# Trying multiple approaches to make the node size of a force directed graph proportional to it's degree

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a force directed graph that works fine. As a next step I am trying to make the node size proportional to it's degree.

I have tried multiple appraches but to no avail.

**First approach**:

My data gets stored in a variable called as **d3GraphData**. I am trying to use the **foreach()** function over nodes the first , followed by the links. For each node , I introduce new attributes **inDegree** and **outDegree** . After this I iterate over each link ; and for each **d.source** , I increment the **outDegree** and for each **d.target** I increment the **inDegree**

```
             var nodes = [];
  var links = [];

  d3GraphData.nodes = nodes;
  d3GraphData.links = links;


 nodes.forEach(function(d) {
  d.inDegree = 0;
  d.outDegree = 0;
});
links.forEach(function(d) {
  nodes[d.source].outDegree += 1;
  nodes[d.target].inDegree += 1;
});
```

This does not seem to work and no **inDegree** and **outDegree** get calculated. When I try to use them in the **r** attribute

```
     node.attr("r",function(d) {return (d.inDegree+d.outDegree) * 2;});
```

I get the expected error:

```
   Error: <circle> attribute r: Expected length, "NaN".
```

**Second approach**:

I read in some documentation that , D3 automatically computes the degree and stores it in the **.weight** attribute. So , I found a way to use it.

```
      node.attr("r", function(d) {return
d3.sum(d3GraphData.links.filter(function(p) {return p.source == d || p.target
== d}), function(p) {return p.weight})})
```

This does not seem to generate any **NaN** error , but the nodes seem to not  appear just like the first approach and I see only links.

May be I am missing something obvious , but I would really appreciate any tips or inputs.

Below is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vishy1988/ztp9bqj8/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find an error in the code used in the first approach. You should have used `node` variable (d3 selection of nodes) instead of using `nodes` variable (Data array) to set the inDegree and outDegree values.

```
  node.each(function(d) {
    d.inDegree = 0;
    d.outDegree = 0;
  });

  lines.each(function(d) {
    d.source.outDegree += 1;
    d.target.inDegree += 1;
  });

  node.attr("r", function(d) {
    var weight = d.inDegree ? d.inDegree : 0 + d.outDegree ? d.outDegree : 0;
    weight = weight > 25 ? 25 : (weight < 5 ? 5 : weight);
    return weight;
  });
```

Here is the updated fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/gilsha/ztp9bqj8/2/)

Comment: I doubt if d3 v4 have weight attribute for nodes. So, the second approach won't work as expected.